# (P and(not(not P or Q))) or( P and Q) equals P

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, predicate-logic

I've been trying to verify the condition above but I get stuck on the passage :

$$(P \land (P \land \lnot Q)) \lor (P \land Q)$$

I don't know how to simplify it since there are two ands and a not Q.

I thought I might use absorption law, but it states that the signs should be different ( in other words, it should be and- or and viceversa). What do you think?

Comment: Use De Morgan's law to simplify ~(~P v Q).

Comment: Since conjunctions are associative, $ P \land ( P \land \lnot Q ) = (P \land P ) \land \lnot Q = ( P \land \lnot Q )$

Comment: The next step is $a\wedge (a\wedge b) = a\wedge b$.  (Idempotence and association)

Comment: Why did you remove your question?

Comment: Hey?? One doesn't normally remove their question once it is answered.

Comment: It is inappropriate to deface questions, even if they were asked by you. Do not do this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The next step is(/steps are) $a\wedge (a\wedge b) = (a\wedge a)\wedge b = a\wedge b$.   (Association and Idempotence)

Answer (score 0):

(P∧(P∧¬Q))∨(P∧Q)

First use the associative law on (P∧(P∧¬Q)) to get ((P∧P)∧¬Q)).  Which law do you apply then to get (P∧¬Q) for the first part?

Then we have (P∧¬Q)∨(P∧Q).  Use one of the distributive laws to condense this.

Do you see how to proceed from there?

Comment: I see, for (P∧¬Q) I would use indempotent law. Thank you!

Comment: Yes.  Good.   You are welcome.